# Reduce cooling power of refrigerator

Tags: cooling

I have a refrigerator which I want to use to store electrical device (I don't want them to get hot). I have successfully drilled a hole through the refrigerator door so that I can supply the electricity inside. The problem is that the refrigerator is causing moisture  to condense into drop and it has the potential of damaging the device, so I would like to increase its temperature to the range around 20 degree celsius instead of its current 4 degree celsius. How can I do that?

Comment: use a suitable thermostat. A hvac (heating/ventilation/air con) supply shop should be able to help you.

Comment: What is your ambient room temperature? Running a fridge will be more expensive and bulky than a cooling fan which will probably do a better job. What's the real problem you're trying to solve? Tip: you can use the HTML entity `&deg;` to get the degrees symbol.

Comment: Put a squirrel cage fan inside to remove condensation or try these https://www.dober.com/electric-vehicle-cooling-systems#electric_vehicle_cooling_systems for preventing low &deg C condensation

Comment: Vents will likely cause more condensation unless force air circulation to reduce the thermal gradient that causes it

Comment: Try the same thing the home brew people use, a external thermostat with the refrigerator plugged into that. It simply turns on or the refrigerator. You could also add a fan inside to help.  Maybe the simplest and most inexpensive is to place the parts in a sealed plastic bag with some moisture absorbers (silica gel). When taking them out let them warm up a bit so moisture does not condense on them.

Answer (score 3):

moisture doesn't come from nowhere, if you leave the door closed there will be no condensation except on the evaporator, and that will drain out of the box.

even replacing the thermostat  with one that goes up to 20 will not prevent condensation if there is sufficiently high humidity outside the refrigerator.

Comment: I'm not sure, the metal and plastic wall inside the refrigerator is pretty low in temperature and it cause a mosture to condense. I guess the mosture in the fridge is the same as in the room, but then it distribute differently on metal/plastic surface.

Answer (score 1):

"*... if you leave the door closed there will be no condensation except on the evaporator.*" That will be true if you put a warm object in. The temperature of the objects will be above the dew point in the fridge. If you open the door and let most air in when the devices have chilled then you will get condensation on the objects

Comment: yeah, that's what I was trying to say.